# Why does the Content Scrambling System have two different length LFSRs

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher, lfsr, disk-encryption, digital-rights-management

CSS uses two LFSRs of length 17 and 25.

If we have two periodic functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ and consider the function $h(t) = (f(t), g(t))$, then $h$ will have period $pq/\gcd(p, q)$
where $p$ and $q$ are the period of $f$ and $g$, respectively, and $\gcd$ is the greatest common divisor.

How does this principle explain the choice for two different LFSRs?

Comment: This principle can explain the period of the generator, and allow comparing that to the period of a generator with 17+25 bits. But _"explain the choice for two different LFSRs"_.. Could it be the [Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42))?